# Download .db file with Android DownloadManager

Tags: java, android, android-studio, download

I am attempting to download a .db file from my organization's website within an Android application and have encountered difficulties. It says the download is unsuccessful.

Here is the code that handles the download:

```
package midamcorp.com.burgerkingapp;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;

public class downloadReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
   File localDBFile = new File(c.getFilesDir(), "bk.db");

        try {

                    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) c.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);


            Uri uriTest = Uri.parse("http://www.midamcorp.com/bk.db");

                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uriTest);


         if (localDBFile.exists()) {
                    localDBFile.delete();
                 }

                    manager.enqueue(request);

               //  }


  }
         catch(Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Error", ex.getMessage());
        }
}

        }
```

Furthermore, when I navigate to this file in my browser, I receive a 404 error; however, I know the path is correct. I have a feeling it has to do with the file extension (.db). How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Furthermore, when I navigate to this file in my browser, I receive a 404 error; however, I know the path is correct

It is not correct, because you are getting 404. URL is invalid or for any other reasons you are not able to reach it, and so is DownloadManager